# Generic value-classes in Scala

Tags: scala, generic-programming

Let's say I have a type `Pos` (for position). In order to gain type-safety the column/row is not represented as `Int` but by types `Col` (column) and a `Row`:

```
case class Pos(col: Col, row: Row) {
  def +(other: Pos): Pos = Pos(col + other.col, row + other.row)
}
```

It's possible to add two positions, which consists of summing columns and rows respectively.

The definition of types `Col` and `Row` would look like this:

```
object Row {
  def apply(value: Int) = new Row(value)
  val zero = new Row(0)
}

object Col {
  def apply(value: Int) = new Col(value)
  val zero = new Col(0)
}

class Row(val value: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def +(other: Row): Row = Row(this.value + other.value)
}

class Col(val value: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def +(other: Col): Col = Col(this.value + other.value)
}
```

This is all fine, but I have the feeling of repeating myself. The definitions are almost identical.

Could I do something to generalize them?

Comment: First of all don't extend from `AnyVal` unless you explicitly need to. Extending from `AnyVal` poses too many restrictions. And I really can not see any need for extending from `AnyVal` in your case. Also... I somehow don't  see any improvements in Type-safety.

Comment: You could use scalaz `Tag` instead of the `AnyVal` classes, e.g. `Int @@ Col` (and then `Row` and `Col` would simply be empty traits).

Answer (score 2):

If you introduce Scalaz and create `Monoid` instances for `Row` and `Col`, you may not reduce your boilerplate, but it would shorten your definition of zero and append some:

```
case class Col(i: Int) extends AnyVal
case class Row(i: Int) extends AnyVal

implicit object rowMonoid extends Monoid[Row] {
  def zero = Row(0)
  def append(a: Row, b: => Row) = Row(a.i |+| b.i)
}

implicit object colMonoid extends Monoid[Col] {
  def zero = Col(0)
  def append(a: Col, b: => Col) = Col(a.i |+| b.i)
}
```

And `Monoids` are composable, so if you stored `Rows` and `Cols` in a map, or tuple or the like, you could just compose them, without hitting the individual elements:

```
val pt1 = (Row(4), Col(15))
val pt2 = (Row(14), Col(5))

val res = pt1 |+| pt2
println(res) // (Row(18),Col(20))
```

I think simplifying the usage will save you more code overall than worrying about trimming down the definitions, assuming `Row` and `Col` are used and added often.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a common trait for Both Row and Col classes:

```
trait Element {
  val value : Int
  def init(value: Int): Element
  def +(other: Element) = init(value + other.value)
}
```

and then use case classes so that you take advantage of the companion object's apply method:

```
case class Row(value: Int) extends Element {
  def init(v: Int) = Row(v)
}

case class Col(value: Int) extends Element {
  def init(v: Int) = Col(v)
}
```

So now you  can add them like that:

```
case class Pos(col: Element, row: Element) {
  def +(other: Pos): Pos = Pos(col + other.col, row + other.row)
}

val p1 = Pos(Col(1), Row(2))
val p2 = Pos(Col(1), Row(2))   
p1 + p2 //res2: Pos = Pos(Col(2),Row(4))
```

However, this allows to create a position with only rows

```
val p3 = Pos(Row(2), Row(3))    
p1 + p3 //res3: Pos = Pos(Col(3),Row(5))
```

So a second step is to bound your `Element` type's `+` method.

```
trait Element[T <: Element[_]] {
  val value : Int
  def init(value: Int): Element[T]
  def +(other: Element[T]) = init(value + other.value)
}
case class Row(value: Int) extends Element[Row] {
  def init(v: Int) = Row(v)
}
case class Col(value: Int) extends Element[Col] {
  def init(v: Int) = Col(v)
}
case class Pos(col: Element[Col], row: Element[Row]) {
  def +(other: Pos): Pos = Pos(col + other.col, row + other.row)
}
```

What you get is that now a row should only add elements of a row type and a Col should only add elements of a Col type. You can still add two positions:

```
val p1 = Pos(Col(1), Row(2))
val p2 = Pos(Col(1), Row(2))
p1 + p2 //res0: Pos = Pos(Col(2),Row(4))
```

but this will not compile:

```
val p3 = Pos(Row(2), Row(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use type variable in your trait

Something like this

```
trait TableElement{
  type T
  def +(t:T):T  
}
```